# Update all values with specific URL to another URL in all the tables

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, migration

I have a DB that contains a lot of data for a WordPress website, That DB contains a URL for the old domain that is repeated, That URL is repeated more that `21500` times.

Now I'm integrating the website to another domain and I want to change that domain to the new URL.

Is it possible to replace them using SQL, PHPMyAdmin?

I tried to find a solution for that, But I couldn't.

UPDATE: There are 90 tables, The `21500` are not in one table or column.

Comment: Do an Update on your table column with Replace(OriginalURLString, NewURLString)

Comment: @Brad, There are 90 tables

Comment: Why not just use a plugin like Duplicator for migration which will do all the replacing for you?